# How can I protect ckeditor change my source code?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, ckeditor, content-management-system

I am making laravel cms system using ckeditor now.
However, ckeditor changes may source code, it means when I copy and paste html to ckeditor in Source code status, after that, I reopen html in Source code status, html is already changed.
Html is as follows;

```
<section class="page-link">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-link__box">
            <div class="page-link__box__cont">
                <div class="page-link__box__cont__btn">
                    <a href="#philosophy">
                        <h4 class="head-h4">aaaa</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-link__box__cont">
                <div class="page-link__box__cont__btn">
                    <a href="#greeting">
                        <h4 class="head-h4">bbbb</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-link__box__cont">
                <div class="page-link__box__cont__btn">
                    <a href="#aboutcompany">
                        <h4 class="head-h4">cccc</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And, ckeditor changes it as follows;

```
<section class="page-link">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-link__box">
            <div class="page-link__box__cont">
                <div class="page-link__box__cont__btn">
                    <h4 class="head-h4">
                        <a href="#philosophy">aaaa</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-link__box__cont">
                <div class="page-link__box__cont__btn">
                    <h4 class="head-h4">
                        <a href="#greeting">bbbb</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="page-link__box__cont">
                <div class="page-link__box__cont__btn">
                    <h4 class="head-h4">
                        <a href="#aboutcompany">cccc</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

After all, `<h4>` tag and `<a>` tag positions are changed with each other;
Please tell me the reason why?
How can I protect ckeditor change my html.

Comment: Dont paste it direct on your ckeditor text area, paste it with as html/source code

Comment: Of course, I pasted it with as html/source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not protect your code, CKEditor will always touch HTML, because it's wysiwyg.
But there's something you can do.

Add buttons with the functionality you need.

Disallow [Advanced Content Filter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html):

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.extraAllowedContent = 'a h4';
```

But I would not recommend to use CKEditor for complex HTML-code. It's intended for paragraphs and something simple. You can use [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io) instead of CKEditor, when working with html and blade templates. And include simple text content, received from CKEditor, to the templates. I think, it's better way.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no effect, Where can I set upper setting? can you indicate the setting file path in CKEditor.

Comment: In ckeditor/config.js. Actually, <a> should be inside of <h4>, that is more correct. It's better to fix css for working with <h4><a>text</a></h4>.